# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Adam' and 'int

Tags: python, optimization, generative-adversarial-network

I use adam optimizer for my cnn but when adjusting learning rate I got unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Adam' and 'int error, how i have to solve this error

I'm using python 3.5 and pytorch 1.1.0

```
def adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, init_lr, epoch, every):
    lrd = init_lr / every
    old_lr = optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']

    #linearly decaying lr
    new_lr = old_lr - lrd
    if new_lr < 0: new_lr = 0
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        param_group['lr'] = new_lr

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Adam' and 'int'
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: seems like you are not passing the correct arguments to this function. Show the code you use to call it

Answer (score 0):

When calling the function, you're not passing the arguments in the correct order.  Specifically, the optimizer (Adam in your case) should be the first argument, not the second.

If this is a method in a class, you forgot the `self` argument.

Answer (score 0):

this is for the optimizing

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr= 0.00001, betas = (0.5, 0.999), weight_decay=0.0000)
```

this is for adjusting learning rate

```
if epoch >= opt.annealStart:
       adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch, opt.annealEvery)
```